# Converting date input to String value in specific format using XQuery

Tags: xquery

I have to create a date string in DDMMYYYY format using xquery. The date input to my xquery will be like "2004-05-02T00:00:00+01:00". As of now i am using the following solution to get the required fromat(02052004),

```
$dateString:= concat(substring($dateInput, 9, 2), substring($dateInput, 6, 2), substring($dateInput, 1, 4));
```

Is there any other way or inbuilt function using which i can convert a date to required string format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've got access to **XQuery 3.0**, you can take advantage of `format-dateTime($date, $picture)`:

```
let $date := xs:dateTime("2004-05-02T00:00:00+01:00")
return format-dateTime($date, "[D,2][M,2][Y,4]")
```

If you haven't (only **XQuery 1.0**), you still can use a more semantic version. As it also has no `format-number(...)` function, I'm using some prepared functions from functx:

```
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com";
declare function functx:pad-integer-to-length
  ( $integerToPad as xs:anyAtomicType? ,
    $length as xs:integer )  as xs:string {

   if ($length < string-length(string($integerToPad)))
   then error(xs:QName('functx:Integer_Longer_Than_Length'))
   else concat
         (functx:repeat-string(
            '0',$length - string-length(string($integerToPad))),
          string($integerToPad))
 } ;

 declare function functx:repeat-string
  ( $stringToRepeat as xs:string? ,
    $count as xs:integer )  as xs:string {

   string-join((for $i in 1 to $count return $stringToRepeat),
                        '')
 } ;

let $date := xs:dateTime("2004-05-02T00:00:00+01:00")
let $date := xs:date($date)
return string-join((
  functx:pad-integer-to-length(day-from-date($date), 2),
  functx:pad-integer-to-length(month-from-date($date), 2),
  functx:pad-integer-to-length(year-from-date($date), 4)
))
```

Decide on your own if you prefer the more bulky, but semantic version or simple string manipulation. Be aware that time zones might lead to different results depending on which one you choose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a XQuery 1.0 processor it will be slighlty complicated. There are functions like `fn:day-from-dateTime()` available, but the would return a single number for a numer below 10, which is quite likely not what you want.

You can write a simply padding function

```
declare function local:pad($number as xs:integer) as xs:string
{
  if ($number<10)
  then concat("0", $number)
  else xs:string($number)
};
```

and use it to construct the date

```
concat(
  local:pad(day-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime($dateInput))),
  local:pad(month-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime($dateInput))),
  year-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime($dateInput))
)
```

If your processor supports XQuery 3.0, the `fn:format-dateTime()` is available and allows easier formatting. The formatting rules are available at http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-xpath-functions-30-20140408/#rules-for-datetime-formatting. For your desired output the following should work:

```
fn:format-dateTime(xs:dateTime($dateInput),"[D01][M01][Y}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

fn:format-dateTime(xs:dateTime($dateInput),"[M01][D01][Y0001]")

to produce 02052004

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this site - http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_mmddyyyy-to-date.html. Just made changes to the last line of the function - $3-$2-$1

```
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com";
declare function functx:mmddyyyy-to-date
       ( $dateString as xs:string? )  as xs:date? {

       if (empty($dateString))
       then ()
       else if (not(matches($dateString,
                    '^\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{4})\D*$')))
       then error(xs:QName('functx:Invalid_Date_Format'))
       else xs:date(replace($dateString,
                    '^\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{4})\D*$',
                    '$3-$2-$1'))
       } ;
```

Usage:

`functx:mmddyyyy-to-date('31-01-2004')`

Output

2004-01-31